# How to implement solidity bitwise in Golang

Tags: solidity, golang, operator

Code in UniswapV3 Solidity contract
[TickBitmap](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/main/contracts/libraries/TickBitmap.sol)

```
uint256 mask = ~((1 << bitPos) - 1);
```

I had founded some example code in Golang:

```
    a := new(big.Int).Exp(big.NewInt(2), big.NewInt(66), nil)
    a.Sub(a, big.NewInt(1))
    b := bitwiseNot(a)

func bitwiseNot(x *big.Int) *big.Int {
    mask := new(big.Int).SetBit(new(big.Int), 256, 1)
    result := new(big.Int).Xor(x, mask)
    return result
}
```

When I Test code on Remix, try `bitpos=66`,
Remix Output:

```
uint256: mask 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039383797031618291433472
```

Golang Output:

```
115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039531370984207967846399
```

How to implement this solidity caculation in golang?

Answer (score 0):

Your mask for the not operation is not correct. `new(big.Int).SetBit(new(big.Int), 256, 1)` is 2^256 while you need 2^256-1 to do bitwise not:
Add one more line to your original function:

```go
func bitwiseNot(x *big.Int) *big.Int {
    mask := new(big.Int).SetBit(new(big.Int), 256, 1)
    mask.Sub(mask, big.NewInt(1))
    result := new(big.Int).Xor(x, mask)
    return result
}
```

If we use some math, we can achieve the same thing without doing bitwise negation code:

1. The value we want to negate is `(1 << bitPos) - 1 = (2^bitPos - 1)`
2. Bitwise negation of the value in N bit is taking the max value in N bits (all N bits = 1) and substract with the value we want. In this case, the max value is `2^256 - 1`

```golang
    bitPos := 66
    // mask = (2^256 - 1) - (2^bitPos - 1)
    mask := new(big.Int).Sub(
        new(big.Int).Sub(
            new(big.Int).Exp(big.NewInt(2), big.NewInt(256), nil),
            big.NewInt(1),
        ),
        new(big.Int).Sub(
            new(big.Int).Exp(big.NewInt(2), big.NewInt(int64(bitPos)), nil),
            big.NewInt(1),
        ),
    )

    fmt.Printf("mask = %s\n", mask.Text(10)) // Decimal representation
    fmt.Printf("mask = %s\n", mask.Text(2))  // Binary representation
```

Comment: Thanks, It works!